# How to Kill CurrentDB using self executed code

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have been researching ways to self execute code that would delete the current database file. I came across a code snippet [here](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-47431.html) that does exactly that for Excel, but this does not seem to translate to Access very well.

```
 Sub KillMeExcel()
 With ThisWorkbook
    .Saved = True
    .ChangeFileAccess Mode:=xlReadOnly
    Kill .FullName
    .Close False
 End With
 End Sub
```

There does not seem to be a `.ChangeFileAccess` Mode in Access, so I haven't gotten further than that.

**Is it possible to delete the current database using VBA code?**

Comment: I've been working with the file SystemObject and tried that but without luck. The idea behind doing this is that I have Users who will need to send the entire Access File via Email. I want to ensure that once they sent the email, that they don't accidentally continue working on that DB file.

Comment: Is there a way to perhaps save the DB under a new name using the SaveAs Method, and then deleting the original? I have not been able to find the SaveAs commands in Access. In Excel this would have been easy.

Comment: Thanks for your input on this!

Comment: Maybe a better approach would be to split the database into frontend with code and backend with tables only. Then (I assume) only the backend would have to be sent and deleted by code in the frontend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is not possible. You will get a *Permission Denied* error - for a reason.

Comment: Is that the definitive answer? Ouch. Then I would need to find a workaround solution.

Comment: Yes, your only option would be to open an external instance/script, as shown by André, to do the dirty job.

Comment: I have to go with both of you.

Answer (score 6):

I would also be wary of sending an open and running Access database via mail.

My workaround would be:

```
Launch an external vbs
DoCmd.Quit
```

and in the vbs:

- Wait in a loop until the .ldb / .laccdb file is gone (i.e. the db is
  closed)
- Send the mail with attached db
- delete the db

Comment: I don't have access to the environments where the DBs will be running. The fact that they are not on a shared network is the main reason for this ugly workaround.

Comment: With @Gustav, and you agreeing that this is not possible I'll take that answer as the definitive one. Thanks for all for waying in on this!

Comment: A .vbs is a simple text file that you could create on-the-fly from your Access VBA code. But this would probably be even uglier. :)

Comment: Would a security / virus software not flag this? My work environment is heavily restricted in this regard

Comment: That is possible, yes. If this were your last resort, you'd have to check with your IT guys, maybe have it whitelisted.